# Estimate knee-position of curve

Tags: r

I have measurements that look like the plot "Measured samples" (see code). From those points I´m trying to find the knee which in this case is at x=80 and y=12 `(p.corners[2, ])`. The plot "Underlying curve" show the trend-line I´m trying to find automatically.

How can I estimate the coordinates of the knee-position? I have hundreds of curves to fit, with about 200 points each.

```
library(ggplot2)
p.corners <- data.frame(rbind(c(0, 6), c(80, 12), c(100, 100)))
colnames(p.corners) <- c("x", "y")
x.a <- 1:p.corners[2, "x"]
y.a <- (p.corners[2, "y"]-p.corners[1, "y"])/(p.corners[2, "x"]-p.corners[1, "x"])*x.a+p.corners[1, "y"]
x.b <- (p.corners[2, "x"]+1):100
y.b <- (p.corners[3, "y"]-p.corners[2, "y"])/(p.corners[3, "x"]-p.corners[2, "x"])*x.b+p.corners[2, "y"]-(((p.corners[3, "y"]-p.corners[2, "y"])/(p.corners[3, "x"]-p.corners[2, "x"]))*p.corners[2, "x"])
x <- c(x.a, x.b)
y <- c(y.a, y.b)
p.random <- data.frame(cbind(x, y))
p.random$y.random <- y + 20*(runif(20)-0.5)

p <- ggplot(p.random, aes(x=x, y=y.random))
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + xlim(0, 100)
p <- p + ylim(0, 100)
p <- p + labs(title="Measured samples")
p
p <- ggplot(p.random, aes(x=x, y=y))
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + xlim(0, 100)
p <- p + ylim(0, 100)
p <- p + labs(title="Underlying curve")
p
```

The underlying curve is one straight line with modest slope, followed by a steep line. The measurements are very much more spread out than in the example plot.

Answer (score 2):

Without actual data it's difficult to tell, but perhaps you should look first at differences computed with `diff`:

```
> rle(round(diff(p.random$y, differences = 1), 3))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:2] 79 20
  values : num [1:2] 0.075 4.4
> rle(round(diff(p.random$y, differences = 2), 3))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3] 78 1 19
  values : num [1:3] 0 4.325 0
> rle(round(diff(p.random$y, differences = 3), 3))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 77 1 1 18
  values : num [1:4] 0 4.325 -4.325 0
```

(The `rle` calls are here only to shorten the output.) Perhaps you'd be looking for a peak of the second-order difference, or a sign change of the third-order difference. If the data is noisy, consider smoothing it up front with `KernSmooth::ksmooth` or `loess`.